# Launch Windows Terminal with multiple commands sequentially

Tags: command-line, terminal, windows-terminal

I want keep WindowsTerminal screen remaining after running command for debugging purpose.
To achieve this, try running the `pause` command after the command completes.

```
wt new-tab powershell "ping stackoverflow.com;pause"
```

But in WindowsTerminal use `;` as a delimiter for separating commands in the wt command line. Even try escape it not work

In many post they are only interested in running commands on multiple panels.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows#examples-of-multiple-commands-from-powershell
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396994/how-to-launch-windows-terminal-with-multiple-commands

I achieve this by another way with powershell's `-NoExit` flag.

```
wt new-tab powershell -NoExit -c "ping stackoverflow.com"
```

But I still have a question to run multiple commands sequentially in WindowsTerminal.

Comment: Thanks for reposting this over here.  In looking for the answer, I came across a possible duplicate question/answer.  That answer seems to work for your use case -- Use ``\`` to escape the semicolon (you were probably trying a backtick, like I did originally).  So for your example, `wt new-tab powershell "ping stackoverflow.com \; pause"`.  If that takes care of it for you, just accept the "duplicate" suggestion (should be in the header for you) and upvote the other question/answer.  If not, let us know, and we can dig in more.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well what you want to achieve, try this:

Make a main.bat where you will going to launch multiple .bat files (having multiple commands sequentially) in separate WindowsTerminal tabs.

example of main.bat:

```
wt -w 0 new-tab start powershell.exe -NoExit c:\batch\commands1.bat 
wt -w 0 new-tab start powershell.exe -NoExit c:\batch\commands2.bat
wt -w 0 new-tab start powershell.exe -NoExit c:\batch\commands3.bat
```

example of commands1.bat:

```
ping stackoverflow.com
ping google.com
echo finished
```

etc.

Running main.bat will open WindowsTerminal with 3 new tabs, in everyone of which the specified commands{0-3}.bat batch file will be executed without closing them after command lines finish executing.

Hope this helps.